# Finding last or "recent" attachment folder

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

Running Outlook 2010. I am trying to replicate, then customize, the Save Attachments or Attachment:Save As process in VBA. It would be nice if I could figure out the most recent file path (where I saved the last attachment) that Outlook remembers, programmatically.

It's not VBA CurDir... (that seems to give location of Office install)

To be explicit, when I first hit Save As... it opens in My Docs (default). 
Then I'll save an attachment as 'C:\User\My Docs\Blah\attachment.ext'. 
The next time I do Save As... it will open in Blah.

How do I find out the path to or possibly update Blah using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.

```
       Dim host As Outlook.Application
       Set host = ThisOutlookSession.Application
       curDir
```

(now gives me what I want)

Bwahahahaahaah!